# SSRS 2005 export to csv - I don't want the header?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Currently my SSRS 2005 server is exporting the names of the textboxes as the header when a report is exported to CSV.  I've tried changing the device information settings in the rsreportserver.config file:

```
<Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.CsvRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.CsvRendering">
            <configuration>
                <DeviceInfo>
                    <NoHeader>true</NoHeader>
                </DeviceInfo>
            </configuration>
        </Extension>
```

After re-starting Reporting Services, I'm still getting the header.  Is the change I made correct?

Comment: I got this information from here:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281(v=SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out why changes to the rsreportserver.config didn't take.

1. I didn't capitalize "Configuration" and "/Configuration".
2. Re-starting reporting services doesn't reload this configuration file; re-starting IIS reloads this configuration file.