# SSRS report - Merge data from different datasources with the same tables

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, rdl

I have 2 databases, one is for Employees, and the another one is for Employees that used to work on the company.

both databases have the same tables but with different data (there is no Employee_ID that will be in both databases).

let's take only employee table.
The fields that I have in employee table is Employee_ID  First_Name and Last_Name.

I want to show them both in the same table:

```
Employee_ID                         First_Name                      Last_Name
```

---

Employee_ID  from datasource 1    First_Name from datasource 1   Last_Name from datasource 1

---

Employee_ID  from datasource 2    First_Name from datasource 2   Last_Name from datasource 2

---

I need to create report (.rdl) with one table that contain the data from these two databases because when I do it in 2 tables (the second table is without header and next to the first table), when I do export to CSV, it create empty row between the tables and add headers to the second table even that I delete the header row/ did hide).

and that effect the filtering on the result in the CSV file (I don't want 
to tell the client manually remove the empty row and the header).

I want to get the databases from the clients (in SQL Server Reporting Services into two different datasource) and that why in the custom query I don't want to use union or join and add the second database.

at the end, it doesn't meter to me if I'm using two or one dataset files, and if it two or one tables in the reports, just need after I do export to CSV, that it will in the file in one table with no empty row or header repeated.

Thank for helping. :)

Comment: This is by design. Check if creating a no header csv export option works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531896/how-to-export-a-csv-without-header-in-ssrs

Comment: The problem with that solution is that I want header on the first table and that it not solve the empty line between the tables